# Python splitting strings and convert them to a list that notices empty fields

Tags: python, mysql, csv, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

it took me the whole day trying to fix this problem but I didn't found a solution so I hope you can help me. I already tried to extract the data from the website. But the problem is that I don't know how to split the list so that 500g converts to 500,g. The problem is that on the website sometimes the quantity is 1 and sometimes 1 1/2 kg or sth. And now I need to convert it into a CSV file and then into a MySQL database. What I want at the end is a CSV file with the columns: ingredients ID, ingredients, quantity, and the unit of the quantity from the ingredient. So for example:
0, meat, 500, g. This is the code I already have to extract the data from [this](https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/3039711456645264/Ossobuco-a-la-Milanese.html) website:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

urls_recipes = ['https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/3039711456645264/Ossobuco-a-la-Milanese.html']
mainurl = "https://www.chefkoch.de/rs/s0e1n1z1b0i1d1,2,3/Rezepte.html"
urls_urls = []
urls_recipes = ['https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/3039711456645264/Ossobuco-a-la-Milanese.html']
ingredients = []
menge = []

def read_recipes():
    for url, id2 in zip(urls_recipes, range(len(urls_recipes))):
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
        for ingredient in soup2.select('.td-left'):
            menge.append([*[re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', ingredient.get_text(strip=True))]])
        for ingredient in soup2.select('.recipe-ingredients h3, .td-right'):
            if ingredient.name == 'h3':
                ingredients.append([id2, *[ingredient.get_text(strip=True)]])
            else:
                ingredients.append([id2, *[re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', ingredient.get_text(strip=True))]])

        read_recipes()
```

I hope you can help me Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the strings containing fractions use the unicode symbols for 1/2 etc., so I think a good way of starting is replacing those by looking up the specific [code](http://unicodefractions.com/) and passing it to `str.replace()`. Splitting up the units and the amount for this example was easy, since they are separated by a space. But it might be necessary to generalize this more if you encounter other combinations.
The following code works for this specific example:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd

urls_recipes = ['https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/3039711456645264/Ossobuco-a-la-Milanese.html']
mainurl = "https://www.chefkoch.de/rs/s0e1n1z1b0i1d1,2,3/Rezepte.html"
urls_urls = []
urls_recipes = ['https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/3039711456645264/Ossobuco-a-la-Milanese.html']
ingredients = []
menge = []
einheit = []


for url, id2 in zip(urls_recipes, range(len(urls_recipes))):
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
    for ingredient in soup2.select('.td-left'):
        # get rid of multiple spaces and replace 1/2 unicode character
        raw_string = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', ingredient.get_text(strip=True)).replace(u'\u00BD', "0.5")
        # split into unit and number
        splitlist = raw_string.split(" ")
        menge.append(splitlist[0])
        if len(splitlist) == 2:
            einheit.append(splitlist[1])
        else:
            einheit.append('')
    for ingredient in soup2.select('.recipe-ingredients h3, .td-right'):
        if ingredient.name == 'h3':
            continue
        else:
            ingredients.append([id2, re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', ingredient.get_text(strip=True))])

result = pd.DataFrame(ingredients, columns=["ID", "Ingredients"])
result.loc[:, "unit"] = einheit
result.loc[:, "amount"] = menge
```

Output:

```py
 >>> result
     ID                                        Ingredients   unit amount
 0    0  Beinscheibe(n), vom Rind, ca. 4 cm dick geschn...             4
 1    0                                               Mehl         etwas
 2    0                                         Zwiebel(n)             1
 3    0                                   Knoblauchzehe(n)             2
 4    0                                         Karotte(n)             1
 5    0                                     Lauchstange(n)             1
 6    0                                    Staudensellerie           0.5
 7    0                                Tomate(n), geschält   Dose      1
 8    0                                        Tomatenmark     EL      1
 9    0                              Rotwein zum Ablöschen
 10   0                       Rinderfond oder Fleischbrühe  Liter    0.5
 11   0                                Olivenöl zum Braten
 12   0                                     Gewürznelke(n)             2
 13   0                                       Pimentkörner            10
 14   0                                  Wacholderbeere(n)             5
 15   0                                      Pfefferkörner
 16   0                                               Salz
 17   0                    Pfeffer, schwarz, aus der Mühle
 18   0                                            Thymian
 19   0                                           Rosmarin
 20   0                            Zitrone(n), unbehandelt             1
 21   0                                   Knoblauchzehe(n)             2
 22   0                                    Blattpetersilie   Bund      1
```